# Devise API recoverable link wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication for my rails app and api.

When I send a reset password link from my api to `/api/v1/users/password` it sends the email but the link in the email goes to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=A2opghht5cy5ATiezGe1`

How do I make it go to `http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=A2opghht5cy5ATiezGe1`

Here is my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: "json" } do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :users
      resources :users
    end
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :users 
end
```

Here is `app/controllers/api/v1/passwords_controller.rb`

```
module Api
  module V1


    class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
      respond_to :json

      def create
        @user = User.send_reset_password_instructions(params[:user])
        if successfully_sent?(@user)
          render :status => 200, :json => {:success => true}
        else
          render :status => 422, :json => { :errors => @user.errors.full_messages }
        end
      end
    end


  end
end
```

Comment: How are you creating the link?

Comment: I'm using the default devise mailer.

Comment: Try moving the devise_for and resources lines above namespace block

Comment: But I need to have a path to create the forgot password token from ```/api/v1/users/password``` as well as all the other devise controllers